# Como fazer um placeholder num TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Como posso simular um *placeholder* usando WPF?

Algo parecido com o *input* do HTML onde você clica no campo ele  some o texto e quando você muda ele volta o texto?

---

Lembrando que é em WPF, porque em Windows forms eu sei só que a forma que eu faço, não consigo fazer no WPF.

Comment: Fonte: [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox/11873521#11873521)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adaptar direto no código WPF, lembrando que este estilo deve ser inserido após a declaração de sua `Window`, ou pode ser aplicada no `Application.Resources` do Application.xaml do projeto.
Eis o resultado!
[image: Resultado]

```
 <Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="Estilo_Placeholder" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 x:Name="Texto" 
                                 Background="Transparent" 
                                 Panel.ZIndex="2" />
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference Texto}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Modo de usar:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Estilo_Placeholder}" Tag="Seu texto (placeholder)"/>
```

Para ler mais sobre estilos, clique [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/wpf-styles-estilizando-sua-aplicacao/32184)